# nodejs как отправить команду и получить ответ через telnet?

Tags: linux, node.js, telnet

Есть сервер на линуксе, для управления используется telnet. То есть подключение идет telnet localhost 1234 и дальше отправляю команды и получаю ответ. Как подобное сделать используя Nodejs?

На сервере установлен teamspeak3 server а так же openvpn server

При подключении к ts все нормально

```
const net = require('net');

const options = {
    port: 10011,
    host: '127.0.0.1'
}

const client = net.createConnection(options, () => {
    client.write('')
})

client.on('data', data =>{
    console.log(data.toString())
    client.end()
})
```

Получаю ответ:

```
TS3
Welcome to the TeamSpeak 3 ServerQuery interface, type "help" for a list of commands and "help <command>" for information on a specific command.
```

а при подключении к openvpn ошибку

```
const net = require('net');

const options = {
    port: 7505,
    host: '127.0.0.1'
}

const client = net.createConnection(options, () => {
    client.write('')
})

client.on('data', data =>{
    console.log(data.toString())
    client.end()
})
```

ошибка

```
node:events:371
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:7505
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1132:16)
Emitted 'error' event on Socket instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:193:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:158:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  errno: -4078,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 7505
}
```

В чем дело не могу разобраться

Comment: `telnet` это чистый TCP-поток. Так что https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_net_createconnection и вперёд

Comment: А OpenVPN точно слушает 127.0.0.1:7505/tcp, а не udp или только внешний интерфейс?